# Scala to find common values between two lists

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a text file in the following format

```
a,b,c,d,e
f,g,h,i,j
b,g,k,l,m
g,h,o,p,q
```

I want an output file that contains only those rows whose values in first column is available in any of the second column. For example in this case values in first column of last two rows are "b" and "g" which are also available somewhere in second column. So my required output has only two rows.

```
b,g,k,l,m
g,h,o,p,q
```

As per my solution, I got two lists of column 1 and column 2 with distinct values. Now, how can I see whether Values in Column 1 is available in Column2. Related Code :

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;

import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import scala.io.StdIn.{readLine, readInt}
import scala.io.Source

object SimpleApp {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val logFile = "src/data/s1.txt"

    val sc = new SparkContext("spark://Hadoop1:7077", "Simple App", "/usr/local/spark",
    List("/usr/local/spark/SimpleSparkProject/target/scala-2.11/simple-project_2.11-1.0.jar"))
    val lD = sc.textFile(logFile).cache()

    val d2Map = lD map(col2)
    val Column2 = d2Map.distinct

    val d1Map = lD map(col1)
    val Column1 = d1Map.distinct

    // Now, here I want only those values in Column1 Which are available in Column2

    //Column2.saveAsTextFile("hdfs://Hadoop1:9000/user/output/distDestination")
  }




  def col2(s:String) : (String) = {
    val kv = s.split(",")
    val k = kv(1)
    k
  }

  def col1(s:String) : (String) = {
    val kv = s.split(",")
    val k = kv(0)
    k
  }

}
```

Comment: What are some of the things you've tried? Please post the code you've been working on so that we know how to further assist you.

Comment: Please see my edited question

Comment: What about `scala> List("b","g","k","l","m").intersect( List("g", "h", "o", "p", "q") )
res4: List[String] = List(g)`

Answer (score 0):

This code written in pure scala, not using the spark, but I hope it will help you.

```
val str = "a,b,c,d,e\n" +
  "f,g,h,i,j\n" +
  "b,g,k,l,m\n" +
  "g,h,o,p,q"

val rows = str.split("\n")
val splittedRows = rows.map(_.split(","))

val stringsInSecondColumn = splittedRows.map(_.apply(1)).toSet    

val result = splittedRows.filter { row =>
  stringsInSecondColumn.contains(row.apply(0))
}
result.foreach(x => println(x.mkString(",")))
```

Lines above result val stringsInSecondColumn is just string parsing.
Than we getting all string in second column and casting container with them to set to achieve linear search time.
And than we just need to filter all rows and check if first value can be found in stringsInSecondColumn set.

In your code you may do next things:

```
val stringsInSecondColumn = lD.map(_.split(",")(1)).toSet
val filteredRows = lD.filter(row => stringsInSecondColumn.contains(row.split(",")(0)))
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: As per your recomendation I added following part in my above code
but I am getting the error mentioned below
val lD = sc.textFile(logFile).cache()
val splittedRows = lD.map(_.split(","))
val stringsInSecondColumn = splittedRows.map(_.apply(1)).toSet

Error:
value toSet is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String]

Comment: @Ahmad try to use distinct instead of toSet. I have never worked with Spark before and didnt know it api. According to their api disctict should help https://spark.apache.org/docs/0.6.0/api/core/spark/RDD.html.